# C# Load CSV into DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

So I have a CSV file:

```
    Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4
    Data11,Data12,Data13,Data14
    Data21,Data22,Data23,Data24
    Data31,Data32,Data33,Data34
    Data41,Data42,Data43,Data44
```

and a `DataGrid` in an WPF project. I cannot, for the life of me, get it to import. What I was trying to do before was add all the columns (`Header1`, `Header2`, `Header3`, `Header4`) then add the rows... but there didn't seem to be any way to add rows. So I tried using `ItemSource`... but no luck.

So... how do I import a CSV file into a `System`.`Windows`.`Controls`.`DataGrid`

**UPDATE**

So I tried this:

```
    DataTable table = CSVReader.ReadCSVFile(fileName, true);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

And it seems to work... somewhat:
[image: The Rows show up, but no columns or content]

**UPDATE 2**

So after turning on `AutoGenerateColumns`, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this library](http://www.stellman-greene.com/CSVReader/). 
It lets you convert any CSV into an object of type DataTable and bind that to the DataGrid like this:

```
DataTable table = CSVReader.ReadCSVFile(fileName, true);
myGridView.ItemSource = table.DefaultView;
myGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

If you already have parsed your CSV into a table, just bind the `ItemSource` to the table's `DefaultView` property and set `AutoGenerateColums` to `true`

Comment: Well this is just sample data... I want it so it can load and display any CSV file.

Comment: I can already convert CSV to DataTable... but it causes an error when I set that as the `ItemsSource` for my `DataGrid`

Comment: You should be able to bind to table.DefaultView which is of type DataView. See above

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed to work somewhat... see updated question.

Comment: Try setting dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true