# WPF Combobox matching placement of DataGrid Column

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I'm playing around with an excel-to-SQL/CSV-to-SQL import.
The my SQL table have only 3 columns, but the import file can have x-number of columns.
My plan was to have an UI that lets the user "map" which column is which with a datagrid and a combobox below each datagridcolumn, where the datagrid contains all the data in the CSV and the combobox contains the SQL columns.
I have made a quick mspaint image to explain my situation. Is this possible to make?

[image: Combobox selection of Coloum header]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Of course this is possible. There are tons of tutorials on the web. You can also buy a book that get you started. Search for 'DataGrid'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible.

The below link may help you to import CSV data to  DataGrid:

[C# Load CSV into DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182656/c-sharp-load-csv-into-datagrid)

And this link helps in binding the columns to the combo boxes.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/

All the best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have these links covered, but my main issue is the placement of the comboboxes and the column width. 
That each column gets its own combobox below it, and with the correct width.
I have tried different options with stackpanels below and similar, but can’t get it to look like my manipulated picture